# Evaluating a complex integral in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, integral

Hello I'm trying to integrate the following function in MATLAB

[image]

And this is my attempt at evaluating it at a given (x,y)

```
fun = @(t,x,y) exp(1i.*(t.^4+x.*t.^2+y.*t));
P = @(x,y) integral(@(t)fun(t,x,y),-Inf,Inf);
P(1,1)
```

According to WolframAlpha the answer is 1.20759 + 0.601534 i  for P(1,1)
but MATLAB returns  -6.459688464052636e+07 - 8.821747942103466e+07i

I am wondering how to enter an integral like this correctly.

I have now also tried evaluating this symbolically and using a taylor series to approximate but still no luck.

```
syms x y t
x=1
y=1
f = exp(1i*(t^4+x*t^2+y*t));
fApprox = taylor(f, t, 'ExpansionPoint', 0, 'Order', 10)
sol=int(fApprox,t,[-inf inf])
```

Any additional suggestions

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In Matlab I get `Warning: Reached the limit on the maximum number of intervals in use. Approximate bound on error is   9.9e+07. The integral may not exist, or it may be difficult to approximate numerically to the requested accuracy`. Try symbolic computation perhaps?

Comment: @LuisMendo  I have tried that and included the code but still no luck

Comment: The integral is highly oscillatory. The absolute value of the integrand is also constant 1. I would not be surprised that this integral does not exist. Even if one assumes a principle value integral it is probably questionable.

Comment: @AndreasH. I'm pretty sure the integral exists (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearcey_integral) as people are able to plot the real parts

Comment: I see, but then I suspect `x` and `y` should be (must be ?) complex quantities. I think there should be damping somewhere in the integrand (i.e x or y with positive imaginary part).

Comment: `x` at least should have positive imaginary part, I would say (otherwise there is no convergence)

Comment: @AndreasH.  Thank you,  I am currently sifting through papers to see how others deal with this.